# SQL Server 2000 install - Using Trusted Connection with Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server

So this is a local version on one box. SQL Server 2000 and Windows 7 (don't ask)....I am assuming that using a Trusted Connection with Windows Authentication should allow me to access the database with my PC credentials?

I know this question screams beginner, and there is no denying that!

Thanks for any help, or advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes...here is a [read](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/SQL_Server_2000_Authentication.html) also.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct.  Trusted connection = Windows Authentication and will use the credentials of the current Windows session.